Why compose adds extra text to Accessibility?
So I'm working on the Accessibility feature in my app.
My problem is, the TalkBack announces extra texts regardless of the clearAndSetSemantics{} fun.
For example to the close button it says: "Close button content desctiption, button Out of list" instead of "Close button content desctiption, button" or for every star it announces: "1 Rating icon item double tap to activate" instead of "1 Rating icon item".
You can reproduce the issue with this code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun Example(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .semantics {
                isTraversalGroup = true
            }
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        IconButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clearAndSetSemantics {
                    contentDescription = "Close button content desctiption, button"
                    testTag = "closeButtonTextTag"
                },
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Close,
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text(text = "Text one description")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text(text = "Text two description")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            for (ratingIndex in 1..5) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(30.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                            .clickable {

                            }
                            .clearAndSetSemantics {
                                contentDescription = "$ratingIndex Rating icon item"
                                testTag = "ratingIconTestTag"
                            },
                        imageVector = if (ratingIndex < 3) {
                            Icons.Default.Star
                        } else {
                            Icons.Filled.Star
                        },
                        contentDescription = "",
                        tint = Color.Unspecified
                    )

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                            .semantics {
                                invisibleToUser()
                                testTag = "textTestTag"
                            },
                        text = "Last text string"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ExamplePreview() {
    Example(Modifier.background(Color.White))
}

If I put the clearAndSetSemantics{} block to the Rating star column it works fine, but in this case the whole column get accessibility focus instead of the icon.
What am I missing ? Or it works as expected?

I don't think it is the best solution, but in my case it worked. So I simple put the Icon into a Box, and defined the semantics on the Box.
The clearAndSetSemantics fun Clears the semantics of all the descendant nodes and sets new semantics.
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(
                start = CloseButtonStartPadding,
                top = CloseButtonTopPadding
            )
            .clearAndSetSemantics {
                contentDescription = closeButtonContentDescription
                testTag = closeButtonTextTag
            }
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = onButtonClick
        ) {
            Icon(
            )
        }
    }


This is expected behavior from TalkBack.
The "out of list" indicates that TalkBack's focus moved from an item within a list to an item outside of the list. "Double tap to activate" is added because Talkback is indicating that an item can be interacted with.
This is not specific to Compose either, this is TalkBack specific behavior that also persists to XML views.

Thanks, but I don't agree with you, because we should be able to re-define the default contentDescription, actually I replaced it in a Button, and it doesn't add extra like "double tap to activate"

@Andreas1234 it's not a matter of agreeing, this is how Talkback works. The source code of TalkBack is available here: https://github.com/google/talkback/
If you are looking to modify TalkBack behavior and override these hints, you are very likely to be making your app work in a way that TalkBack users would not expect it to behave in. TalkBack users are able to disable these additional hints from their side of things.
If it does not make sense for "Double-tap to activate to be announced", then maybe you should be looking for a component other than Button or disable the button.

Maybe you are right, but it doesn't explain why I'm able to rewrite some compose element default hint, and why I'm not to others. Actually it's my client expectation, for example the close button should be "... double tap to close the survey"
